# MAUI - Neat way to perform a Spotify logout

Tags: android, maui, spotify

So far I managed to perform the logout in Spotify via the following code

```
private async void OpenLogOut_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var logoutUrl = "https://www.spotify.com/logout/";
    bool browserResult = await Browser.Default.OpenAsync(logoutUrl, BrowserLaunchMode.SystemPreferred);
}
```

But I would like to achieve the same without opening the browser, so the user does not get distracted.

I am using the library SpotifyAPI.Web to interact with Spotify API, but I could not find any useful method to achieve the logout.

Any idea?

### UPDATE

I also tried to create a platform independent inteface and class to clear the browser cookies

```
private async void OpenLogOut_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var logoutUrl = "https://www.spotify.com/logout/";
    var cookieMngt = DependencyService.Get<ICookieMngt>();
    if (cookieMngt != null)
    {
    cookieMngt.ClearCookies("https://www.spotify.com");        
    }
}
```

here the interface

```
namespace myapp
{
    public interface ICookieMngt
    {
        void ClearCookies(string url);
    }

}
```

and this the CookieManager class

```
using myapp.Platforms;
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(CookieMngt))]
    namespace WiseJam.Platforms
    {
        public class CookieMngt: ICookieMngt
        {
      
            public void ClearCookies(string url)
            {
                try
                {
                    Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance.RemoveAllCookies(null);
                    Android.Webkit.CookieManager.Instance.Flush();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    // Handle any exceptions as needed
                    Console.WriteLine("Error clearing cookies: " + ex.Message);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

and in mauiprogram.cs

```
DependencyService.Register<ICookieMgmt, CookieMgmt>();
```

everything compiles, but it does not seem to work. Whenever I try to login , it does not ask for user and password, it takes the authentication token already present and no user intervention is needed.
Could it be that this auth token is not a cookie?